# Unable to write AVPacket side data to mp4 file using ffmpeg/libav

Tags: video, ffmpeg, libav, libavcodec, libavformat

I want to save some metadata per frame of the video. AVPacketSideData looked good for the same. But, I dont think its getting written to the mp4 file. The parsing code gives `side_data_elems` as `0`. I tried opening the mp4 file using hex editor but the side data is missing there as well.

Below is the method that I am using to write an encoded frame to a mp4 file. This is called after the mp4 header is written and before `write_trailer` is called.

```
int WriteNextFrame(uint8_t* data, int size, bool isKeyFrame)
{
    // side data
    AVDictionary *frameDict = NULL;

    int set_res = av_dict_set(&frameDict, "custom_msg", "hello" , 0);
    if (set_res < 0)
    {
        printf("FAILED TO SET DICT");
    }
    
    //verify if the dict is set
    AVDictionaryEntry *tag = nullptr;
    tag = av_dict_get(frameDict, "custom_msg", tag, AV_DICT_IGNORE_SUFFIX);
    std::cout << tag->key << " : " << tag->value << std::endl;

    // Pack dictionary to be able to use it as a side data in AVPacket
    int frameDictSize = 0;
    uint8_t *frameDictData = av_packet_pack_dictionary(frameDict, &frameDictSize);
    if (!frameDictData)
    {
        printf("FAILED TO PACK DICTIONARY");
    }

    // Free dictionary not used any more
    av_dict_free(&frameDict);

    // side data end
    ++mProcessedFramesNum;

    AVPacket pkt;
    av_init_packet(&pkt);

    AVCodecContext *c = mpStreamVideo->codec;

    mpStreamVideo->pts.val = mProcessedFramesNum;

    pkt.pts = av_rescale_q(mpStreamVideo->pts.val, c->time_base, mpStreamVideo->time_base);
    pkt.dts = pkt.pts;
    pkt.stream_index = mpStreamVideo->index;
    pkt.data = data;
    pkt.size = size;
    
    std::cout << "Packet Size before adding side data <" << pkt.size << ">\n";
    std::cout << "Side Data <" << pkt.side_data_elems << ">\n";

    // Add side_data to AVPacket which will be decoded
    int av_error = av_packet_add_side_data(&pkt, AVPacketSideDataType::AV_PKT_DATA_STRINGS_METADATA, frameDictData, frameDictSize);
    if (av_error < 0)
    {
        av_freep(&frameDictData);
        printf("FAILURE TO WRITE SIDE DATA");
    }

    std::cout << "Packet Size after adding side data <" << pkt.size << ">\n";
    std::cout << "Side Data <" << pkt.side_data_elems << "," << pkt.side_data->data << "," << pkt.side_data->size << ">\n";

    if (isKeyFrame)
    {
        pkt.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
    }

    // Write the compressed frame in the media file
    if (av_write_frame(mpFormatCtx, &pkt))
    {   
        msdk_printf(MSDK_STRING("FFMPEG: Error while writing video frame\n"));
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

I have also tried using `av_interleaved_write_frame` instead of `av_write_frame`.
I have also looked into the source code [here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/90a0da9f14eecd7531fba667f3f854931e1377ae/libavformat/mux.c#L1215), and both those functions are supposed to write the side data to the frame.

Following is the output when I run this function. Since, it is the same for every frame, I am adding only sample output:

```
custom_msg : hello
Packet Size before adding side data <95728>
Side Data <0>
Packet Size after adding side data <95728>
Side Data <1,custom_msg,17>
```

Edit 1:
I have tried setting the use_metadata_tags flag. However, it only helps in writing custom metadata to header and not AVPacket side data.

```
AVDictionary *options = NULL;
av_dict_set(&options, "movflags", "use_metadata_tags", 0); 
avformat_write_header(mpFormatCtx, &options);
av_dict_free(&options);
```

Edit 2:
I have also tried setting the `AVFMT_FLAG_KEEP_SIDE_DATA` flag in the context as suggested [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/libav-user@ffmpeg.org/msg08581.html) but that did not help me either.

```
AVDictionary *options = NULL;
av_dict_set(&options, "movflags", "use_metadata_tags", 0);
mpFormatCtx->flags |= AVFMT_FLAG_KEEP_SIDE_DATA;
avformat_write_header(mpFormatCtx, &options);
```

Comment: did you find the solution? please post if you or anyone else has it

Comment: @xyfix I didn't. You can try to use bento4 library.